Exception while writing data to kusto from Azure Synapse notebook
While writing to Kusto from Azure Synapse notebook using the below pyspark code. I get an exception if the table already exists.
df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.synapse.datasource") \
    .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "<link service name>") \
    .option("kustoDatabase", "<Database name>") \
    .option("kustoTable", "<Table name>") \
    .option("tableCreateOptions","CreateIfNotExist") \
    .mode("Append") \
    .save()

Exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
    at com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasink.KustoWriter$.$anonfun$write$3(KustoWriter.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)

Versions in synapse pool
Spark 3.3
Python 3.10
Scala 2.12.17
Java 11

From the error message, it seems your dataframe has a column with string data and you are trying to load that column into Kusto table column, where its datatype is object type.

Check your column datatypes in dataframe and Kusto table and make sure
they are matching and then perform write operation.


Kusto table has string data type as well. It works if table is created by the pyspark code when it runs for the first time. Next run throws the error. So I doubt if target data type mismatch is issue here
